# i2c problem on Raspberry pi2 running Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, i2c, raspbian-jessie

I am following this [tutorial](http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/interfacing-raspberry-pi-and-mpu-6050.html)

It did not work and I looked for help online but still I cannot make the i2c works.

This is my current condition.
If you need more data, please let me know.

Could anybody help me?

```
sudo nano /etc/modules

i2c-bcm2708
#i2c-bcm2835
i2c-dev
```

and

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/raspi-blacklist.conf

#blacklist spi-bcm2708
#blacklist i2c-bcm2708
```

also config

```
#dtparam=i2c=on1=on
#dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=i2c_vc=on
device_tree=on
dtparam=spi=on
```

[image]

Comment: It's unclear what your asking, what exactly is not working?

Comment: According to some tutorial, I should get 1b instead of uu.  Running sudo i2cget -y 1 0x1b 0x75 also results error: device or resource busy.

Comment: If `i2cdetect -y 1` shows that output it is working -- or at least there is not much reason to believe it isn't.  Do you mean there's a device attached that's not working?

Comment: `UU` I think could mean a kernel module is using a device at that address.  Judging by the `lsmod` output, this could be the case.  *If* you have a device attached, what it is it?

Comment: I am writting via cellphone now so cannot paste the link. In the next page of the tutorial I mentioned above, there is the sourcecode to retrieve data from mpu6050. Running that python code will give me error: device or resource busy. From here, I assume that the address uu is related to this problem. This is my first time playing with i2c.

Comment: http://blog.bitify.co.uk/2013/11/reading-data-from-mpu-6050-on-raspberry.html?m=1

Comment: Running i2cdetect also results no i2c-bus specified.

Comment: That tutorial is 3 years old and has nothing to do with currect Raspbian using Device Tree

Answer (score 1):

if you can see o/p at terminal using sudo i2cdetect -y 1 it means you have installed correct driver. few things you can check.

1. did you enable I2C in boot config.
   if yes then i believe your master I2C is working fine( raspberry pi I2C).
2. now move to your slave, did you check few things

   a. what is your slave device voltage level. is it 3.3v or 5V. pi i2c is 3.3v.

   b. are you using the pull up. i2c wont work if you are not using pull up.

I use this [raspberry Pi I2C adapter](https://www.controleverything.com/products?f[0]=field_assigned_categories%3A6124&f[1]=field_assigned_categories%3A6207), it has on board pull up, level sifter. it makes real easy to use I2C.

if you are having problems with i2c code you can find some help over here. [Java,python I2C code for Pi](https://github.com/ControlEverythingCommunity)

Comment: answer #1, yes.
answer #2a, it uses 3.3V, MPU6050 board.
#2b it uses 3.3V so I do not need to worry about the pull up resistor, do I?
I solder the header for the MPU6050 board now, and it works. I was not soldered last night when I start this post. I thought it would be just fine without soldering it because the led in the board was turned on.
Thanks anyway for everybody here who gave me suggestion. I appreciate it.

Comment: answer #1, yes.
answer #2a, it uses 3.3V, MPU6050 board.
#2b it uses 3.3V so I do not need to worry about the pull up resistor, do I?
I solder the header for the MPU6050 board now, and it works. I was not soldered last night when I start this post. I thought it would be just fine without soldering it because the led in the board was turned on.
Thanks anyway for everybody here who gave me suggestion. I appreciate it.
The address should be 0x68. it shows this value now. But the register 0x1b still shows UU. I do not know why. I only connect 1 i2c device.
Thanks again.